# Under Windows 7 cmd.exe, why do both utf8(65001) and gbk(936) display Chinese filename correctly?

Tags: windows, command-line, encoding

Under Win7 cmd.exe, running the following commands will reproduce the situation I faced today:

(to clarify, my D: partition is formatted as NTFS.)

```
D:\...\_play\notes> chcp
Active code page: 65001
```

---

```
D:\...\_play\notes>dir /b
输入.txt
输出.txt
```

---

```
D:\...\_play\notes> chcp 936
活动代码页: 936                 (the chinese version of "Active Code Page: 936")
```

---

```
D:\...\_play\notes>dir /b
输入.txt
输出.txt
```

This is the behavior of `dir` command, and when compared with `type` command, it looks even more confusing.

```
D:\...\_play\notes>chcp
活动代码页: 936                 (the chinese version of "Active Code Page: 936")
```

---

```
D:\...\_play\notes>type 输入.txt
====== 璺ㄧ晫鍙傝€冭祫婧愪俊鎭緭鍏ュ獟浠?=====   (text garbled as the file is encoded in utf8)
```

---

```
D:\...\_play\notes> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
```

---

```
D:\...\_play\notes>type 输入.txt
====== 跨界参考资源信息输入媒介 ======
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filenames are stored as UTF-16LE in NTFS and VFAT, and the file functions know how to convert this to the current CP (if possible). File contents are read as bytes, and so appear garbled under anything but their appropriate CP.

Comment: Thanks for clarify the underlying difference between them.

Comment: Adding a BOM to the beginning of the file can help. -- Whoops, I meant to revise this before sending, as it just came in to my mind, that Notepad actually does that when saving.